# Sort long list of forward declarations and delete all duplicates

Tags: powershell, resharper

I have a huge header file full of forward declarations and I wanted to sort them alphabetically to have a better overview and delete all duplicates.

the file has around 400 lines and looked as follows:

```
namespace AnimalClothing
{
    class Cat_Gloves;
    class Dragon_Hat;
    class Ant_Shoes;
    class Lion_Glasses;
    class Dragon_Hat;
    ...
}
```

I could not found a way to do this with **ReSpharper** so I just copied the content without the namespace-brackets into a .txt file and used PowerShell to do the job.

```
Get-Content forwardDeclarations.txt | ForEach-Object {
   $Line = $_.Trim() -Split '\s+'
   New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
      ClassKeyword = $Line[0]
      ClassName = $Line[1]
   }
 } | Sort-Object ClassName -Unique > SortedWithoutDuplicate.txt
```

The output was

```
ClassName                             Keyword
---------                             -------

Alpaca_Boots;                         class 
Anaconda_Socks;                       class 
Ant_Shoes;                            class  
Ape_Jumper;                           class
```

To get the correct order of the columns again (class in front of class name) I sorted it by the Sort-Object `ClassKeyword`

```
Get-Content SortedWithoutDuplicate.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $Line = $_.Trim() -Split '\s+'
    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
         Keyword = $Line[0]
         ClassName = $Line[1]
    }
} | Sort-Object Keyword  > EndResult.txt
```

The result at the end is the one I wanted but it looks like a very over-complicated script. Does anybody know how to solve this problem in a more elegant way?

Comment: It looks like R# is missing an inspection to catch duplicate forward declarations. I've filed a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-35102/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject ...`, use [the following syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3#creating-a-pscustomobject) (supported since PowerShell 3.0):

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    ClassKeyword = $Line[0]
    ClassName = $Line[1]
}
```

This specific source code construction - casting a hashtable literal to `[PSCustomObject]` - will cause PowerShell to create a new custom object that preserves the member order from the source code.

---

As an alternative, you can construct an *ordered* dictionary and pass that to `New-Object` (or cast it to `[PSCustomObject]` like the example above), and it'll preserve insertion order as well - very useful when the "shape" of the object might be dynamic or otherwise not known up front:

```
# cast a hashtable literal to `[ordered]` to create an ordered dictionary
$objectProperties = [ordered]@{
  Name = "Name Goes Here"
}

# now we can (conditionally) add things to the property table before turning it into an object
if ($shouldAddIdToObject) {
  $objectProperties['Id'] = Get-Random
}

# ... and then convert it to an object with the same member order
[PSCustomObject]$objectProperties
# this will work with New-Object as well:
# New-Object PSCustomObject -Property $objectProperties
```